# why can't python unzip a password protected zip file created by winrar using the zip method?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I have searched the web high and low but still couldn't find a solution for the above problem. Does anyone out there know why and if so how it can be done?

```
psw="dg"

ZipFile.extractall("data.zip", None, psw)
```

The error that I've got:

```
TypeError: unbound method extractall() must be called
with ZipFile instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: Documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html, see ZipFile.open(name[, mode[, pwd]])

Comment: Thanks for your response but though the document says this it does not work that way and I can't find a single example anywhere on the web. It is strange! It is as if no one ever zipped a password protected file using the zip method in python and if they did never spoke about it!

Comment: actually, @Stefan gave you perfectly correct link. :) You did not read documentation properly, that's the issue. See my answer below, please.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because you are using it wrong. :) From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall):

> [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html).[extractall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall)([path[, members[, pwd]]])
>
> Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory.
> **path specifies a different directory to extract to**. members is optional and must be a subset of the list returned by namelist(). pwd
> is the password used for encrypted files.

So you should call that this function for ZipFile object, not as static method. And you should not pass name of archive as a first argument. :)

this way it'll work:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('data.zip') as zf:
    zf.extractall(pwd='dg')
```

**EDIT**, in newer versions use:

```
zf.extractall(pwd=b'dg')
```

Comment: Thank You, the above worked  and I accept your answer. But I noticed that the extractall method took quite some time to finish. Around 5 minutes to be exact. I zipped 8 files consisting of bmp, png, jpeg, wav, ogg and mp3 all of a total size of 10.7Mb . Why is that? I have had to wait for so long on such a small size. Would like to know more on this. :)

Comment: An answer to @wookie's old question of why ZipFile is so slow: The documentation states `Decryption is extremely slow as it is implemented in native Python rather than C.`

Comment: it actually zf.extractall(pwd=b'dg')

Comment: @LarrySong Thanks for the mentioning ```b```. This is the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

To offer the exact syntaxt without acronym:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

str_zipFile = 'FileZip.zip'
str_pwd= 'xxxx'

with ZipFile(str_zipFile) as zipObj:
  zipObj.extractall(pwd = bytes(str_pwd,'utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some files do not know what they are from and have long extract.

For example, if it is not extracted for 60 seconds or the time is passed, I want to delete the original file to cancel the operation.

```py
import pyzipper

with pyzipper.AESZipFile('test.zip', 'r', compression=pyzipper.ZIP_LZMA, encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as extracted_zip:
        extracted_zip.extractall(pwd=str.encode("@apkclub"))
        os.remove(test.zip)
```