# Unzipping Password protected folders using Python

Tags: python, zip, password-protection

I have some 100 folders zipped and password protected.
To unzip them using python script I can use:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip","r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("targetdir").
```

But how to give password. Suppose the password is 'password'. How van i unzip and print all the folders using python script.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250/create-an-encrypted-zip-file-in-python

Comment: It's explained in the methods documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall

Comment: `extractall` takes a password as argument: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336859/why-cant-python-unzip-a-password-protected-zip-file-created-by-winrar-using-the

Answer (score -1):

Well , according to the documentation, just add the password in your code.

ZipFile.extractall([path[, members[, pwd]]])

Source: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html